# Declare recursivley method chaining in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function that returns dynamic object in vanilla JS:

```
function myFunc(props) {
  return Object.keys(props).reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc, [key](val) {
      console.log(val);
      return this;
    } 
  }), {});
}
```

And an object with that function above:

```
const myProps = {
  counter: 0,
  isCounting: false,
}

const obj = {
  myFunc: myFunc(myProps),
  anotherFunc: () => {},
  moreFunc: () => {},
}
```

And I want to decalre this object in my `.d.ts` file but I'm not sure what is the best way to define a type for recursive method chaining..

I tried using the following type:

```
type Obj<T> = {
  myFunc: () => Record<keyof T, () => this>;
  anotherFunc: () => void;
  moreFunc: () => void;
}
```

But the `this` keyword is referring to the type instance itself and not the `myFunc` object. Meaning I get also the `anotherFunc` and `moreFunc` in it instead of just the dynamic keys from `myProps`.

Can someone help with this implementation?

Comment: `foo(val: any) : this` to show it's a fluent interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `this` in a TypeScript interface:

```
interface Obj {
    [key: string]: (val: string) => this
}

const obj: Obj = {
  foo(val) {
    console.log('foo:', val);
    return this;
  },
  bar(val) {
    console.log('bar:', val);
    return this;
  }
}
```

I've assumed that the `val` arguments are string.

Edit: I've just seen your comment on your post - you can capture the key dynamically with `[key: string]`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for the help, i just realised i did not explained my problem correctly so please see edit..